# I get an error everytime i import Animated from Reanimated 2 into my Expo project. Error below

Tags: expo, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

The error --> Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find @ReactModule annotation in com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerModule

Here is where i try to import it:

```js
import Animated, { SlideInUp, SlideInDown } from "react-native-reanimated";


const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }: any) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Navigation navigation={navigation} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Check if this solve your issue: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/841#issuecomment-559498002

Comment: So, I am new to Mobile Dev, and i am using expo, please pardon me for asking; do i need to create an index.js and put in that code

Comment: There should be an index.js file in root of the project right? From there the project starts executing

Comment: There is normally no Index.js file in Expo projects

Comment: Oho sorry I haven't much experience in expo